# Clicking a button to load a map layer, a variable (src) is returned as not defined, despite a function defining it?

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, button

Hi I have a button on a website that when users click on it, a google map is supposed to load with a layer on it (kml file).

Clicking the button runs three functions. 
1. The function to define what src (the url call to the kml file) is. (concatenation is used here)
2. The function to load the KML file 
3. The function to initialize the map.

The problem is the map loads but the layer does not. The console log shows the correct url is being created in step 1, but the log also says that src is not defined, I can only assume step 1 is not being read by 2 & 3!!!

Here is the code:

```
<button class="button1" onclick="myFunctiongr(); loadKmlLayer();        initialize()">R</button>
<script>
 function myFunctiongr(){
  var gr = [];
  gr.push(url.join('')); *This calls a word from another var*
  var name = gr[0];
  var map; 
  var src = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/mziks0p2lkq4dqb/"+name+".kml?dl=1";
  console.log(src);
 }


function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map
  });
}


function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.50275896, -0.11535645),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

    loadKmlLayer(src, map);
}
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,initialize);
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this:

http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/

Then try:

```
<script>
 var src;

 function myFunctiongr(){
  var gr = [];
  gr.push(url.join('')); *This calls a word from another var*
  var name = gr[0];
  var map; 
  src = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/mziks0p2lkq4dqb/"+name+".kml?dl=1";
  console.log(src);
 }
...
```